# locked textbox property set to true at worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Hello i have textboxes (activeX control) at my worksheet and i have set its locked to true from property tab but it seems its not working at all the only way to prevent value in those textboxes being changed manually was to set the enable to false but i can't change the font color to black. does anyone has suggestions?

thanks before.

[image]

this is code have used so far

```
Private Sub locktextboxes()

Dim NamaBarangTextBox As Object
Set NamaBarangTextBox = Sheet1.NamaBarang

With NamaBarangTextBox
    .Locked = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: sorry i edited my post with my code

Comment: Please, try declaring the variable in the next way: `Dim NamaBarangTextBox As MSForms.ComboBox` and then, use `Set NamaBarangTextBox = Sheet1.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object`. In this way, it should work as you need and you will benefit of intellisense suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot explain what is the meaning of `NamaBarangTextBox.Locked` (obviously the property exists, else you would get a runtime error), but to set the box to readOnly, you need to access the locked-(sub)property of the `Object`-property:

Try

```
With NamaBarangTextBox.object
    .Locked = True
End With
```

Comment: thank you! it works like a charms. i don't know why i just change one text box property from the code but all other textboxes starting to work with out me need to make code for those textboxes.